# If one prays only at mosque does this indicate ar-riya?

Tags: hadith, salat

Prophet prayed atleast 13 units of prayer at his house (11 units of night prayer and 2 units of fair sunnah)

If an individual prays only at mosque and doesnt pray at home does this amount to ar-riya?

Comment: This is not a kind of question that could be answered by affirmation or rejection it rather depends on the individual, his reasons, situation, and intentions not on what he/she does

Answer (score 0):

Salam alikom,

Ar-riya is something you and only you can detect within yourself, if you feel that you go to the mosque because you focus on your prayer and you perform it on the best ways and that's the only reason then you're good, but if you feel that you go to show people you are committed and that you're a good practitioner then you should fix this feeling.

And for your information the sunna is to pray the 5 prayers in mosque but the Nafila the other none obligatory prayers are best performed in your home, so this way you'll be following the sunna which is much better.